# How to recursively parse an expression?

Tags: c, parsing, recursion

I'm writing a small language, and I'm really stuck on expression parsing. I've written a LR Recursive Descent Parser, it works, but now I need to parse expressions I'm finding it really difficult. I do not have a grammar defined, but if it helps, I kind of have an idea on how it works even without a grammar. Currently, my expression struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct s_ExpressionNode {
    Token *value;
    char expressionType;

    struct *s_ExpressionNode lhand;
    char operand;
    struct *s_ExpressionNode rhand;
} ExpressionNode;
```

I'm trying to get it to parse something like:

`5 + 5 + 2 * (-3 / 2) * age`

I was reading [this](http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/Misc/exp_parsing.htm) article on how to parse expressions. The first grammar I tried to implement but it didn't work out too well, then I noticed the second grammar, which appears to remove left recursion. However, I'm stuck trying to implement it since I don't understand what P, B means, and also U is a `-` but the `-` is also for a B? Also I'm not sure what `expect(end)` is supposed to mean either.

Comment: And your code? And your objective? You really must define your task before trying to implement it.

Comment: I had some code for the first grammar, but it wouldn't work since it was left recursive. The second grammar I saw on the site seemed to fix that, but I don't have any code since I'm stuck on how to implement it. I don't really understand the code in the articles examples, and I didn't understand the grammars meaning.

Comment: I'm assuming you just want to parse simple arithmetic expressions. Did you construct a parse tree during the parsing process? You could recursively travel down the tree and then evaluate the expression from the bottom-up.

Comment: You should understand that many commenters here are not interested in your links, but how you are trying to implement the ideas in code.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that I don't need to evaluate the expression, even if I were to just store each token from the expression into a list or something. And yes, an abstract syntax tree is constructed. And it depends what you mean by simple arithmetic expressions, something like in my post is what I'm trying to parse.

Comment: @JonBleins I'm actually a little confused where you're stuck--can you clarify for me? You said you wrote a recursive descent parser and it works, and that you've constructed a parse tree. Doesn't that mean you've successfully parsed the string? If you don't want to evaluate the expression, what else is there to do?

Comment: Ohh, my bad, the AST is constructed for everything but expressions. I'm trying to parse the expression to an AST Node.

Comment: By the way, have you considered using some kind of tool to help you with your parser?  try **flex(1)** / **bison(1)** for that and you'll never do parsing again without some toolkit like these.

Comment: Ahh, but I wont learn if I just get a tool to do it for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "Recursive-descent recognition" section of the article you linked, the `E`, `P`, `B`, and `U` are the non-terminal symbols in the expression grammar presented.  From their definitions in the text, I infer that "E" is chosen as a mnemonic for "expression", "P" as mnemonic for "primary", "B" for "binary (operator)", and "U" for "unary (operator)".  Given those characterizations, it should be clear that the terminal symbol "-" can be reduced either to a `U` or to a `B`, depending on context:

```
unary:   -1
binary: x-1
```

The `expect()` function described in the article is used to consume the next token if it happens to be of the specified type, or otherwise to throw an error.  The `end` token is defined to be a synthetic token representing the end of the input.  Thus

```
expect(end)
```

expresses the expectation that there are no more tokens to process in the expression, and its given implementation throws an error if that expectation is not met.

All of this is in the text, except the reason for choosing the particular symbols `E`, `P`, `B`, and `U`.  If you're having trouble following the text then you probably need to search out something simpler.